# Лежит ли точка на прямой

Tags: математика, геометрия

Как определить, лежит ли точка (*x<sub>3</sub>*; *y<sub>3</sub>*) на прямой, проходящей через точки (*x<sub>1</sub>*; *y<sub>1</sub>*) и (*x<sub>2</sub>*; *y<sub>2</sub>*)?

Comment: У вас есть наработки по решению данной задачи? Если имеется то добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Напоминаю закрывающим, что простые вопросы не запрещены даже в том случае когда автор вопроса явно прогулял школьную математику.

Answer (score 8):

Уравнение прямой, проходящей через точки (x1;y1) и (x2;y2), обычно записывается как

```
x - x1    y - y1
------- = -------
x2 - x1   y2 - y1
```

Чтобы избавиться от деления, можно преобразовать уравнение:

```
(x - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (x2 - x1) * (y - y1) = 0
```

Осталось сюда подставить точку (x3, y3).

Comment: "обычно записывается как" - первый раз вижу такую форму. Каноническое уравнение выглядит по другому: `(x - x1) / (x2 - x1) = (y - y1) / (y2 - y1)`. Хотя, конечно, они эквивалентны, но в канонической записи точки не пропадают

Comment: @АндрейNOP этот вариант не обобщается на три и более точек... Впрочем, он тоже существует и объективно лучше. Спасибо за напоминание.